# Error de Conexión, Excepción de coincidencia ambigua ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

tengo un conflicto al momento de rutear, hice este codigo de ruta, si yo comento la segunda ruta me sale bien, me aparece la primera vista que es el Login pero cuando pongo la segunda ruta osea lo habilito o descomento al momento de arrancar me sale error de coincidencia ambigua y no entiendo a que se refiere por favo su apoyo.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapAreaRoute(
     name:  "Principal",
     areaName:  "Principal",
     template:   "{controller=Principal}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    });
```

[image: Adjunto la imagen de Error que me sale]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que observo es que no defines un template que diferencie las dos rutas, ademas creo que `MapAreaRoute` deberia definirlo primero

```
 routes.MapAreaRoute(
     name:  "Principal",
     areaName:  "Principal",
     template:   "Principal/{controller=Principal}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Fijate como agrego el nombre del area en el `template`

[AmbiguousMatchException using MapAreaRoute with ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7772)

O puedes dejarlo que sea opcional pero debes definir el `[Area("NombreArea")]` en el controller

[ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Areas](https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/08/25/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-areas/)

Comment: Lo que sucede que ya puse '[Area("NombreArea")]' tanto como para elcontrolador del PRINCIPAL Y USUARIOS para que se idenfiquen que estan en la carpeta Area pero aun asi no sale error y me frustra

Comment: pero cambiaste el MapAreaRoute ? porque si revisas el ultimo articulo usa el MapRoute unicamente

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi el error como estoy en la version 2.2 de asp.net tengo que deshabilitar el codigo:

//services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);